# 3DTouch activating but responding too late

Tags: bed-leveling, 3dtouch, artillery-sidewinder-x1

I installed a knockoff BLTouch called the 3DTouch on my Sidewinder X1. The sensor triggers correctly, however, the printer responds to the signal way too late.

For example, I was testing it and decided to trigger it with my finger to see if it was responding at all. After the trigger the printer continued downwards for another 3-4 inches, this would put the head below the bed if I let the bed trigger it. The printer just seems to get the message way too late.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before, part of me thinks it's a calibration issue but honestly it is so far off that I am not sure.

I think it is firmware but I followed this tutorial, [Touch Mi vs BLtouch on the Artillery3D X1 + MKS TFT babystepping](https://youtube.com/watch?v=V3zEJGOcz7s), specifically for the sidewinder X1 to a T so I don't know what I am missing.

The head is stopping once triggered, it's just stopping too late. If I trigger it while it is up high when it goes down a couple of inches and then starts the rest of the self-level procedure.

Comment: This sounds like the firmware isn't correctly configured, have you double checked your changes? Do note that the quality of the kick-off sensors isn't that good, I've had multiple fail, the original works fine. The retraction of the pin does not necessarily imply that the signal arrives correctly to the printer controller board.

Comment: I think it is firmware as well but I followed this tutorial specifically for the sidewinder X1 to a T so i don't know what i am missing.
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3zEJGOcz7s

The head is stopping once triggered, its just stopping too late. If I trigger it while it is up high when it goes down a couple of inches and then starts the rest of the self-level procedure.

Comment: If the pin retracts, that means that the sensor itself is working fine (unless a huge firmware bug is present, which is unlikely) and detected the touch. I would recheck the firmware configuration.